# Is there a PPA for the latest proftpd security issue? (May 18th 2015)

Tags: ppa, ftp, proftpd

I would need the  1.3.4e/1.3.5 package for precise (12.04).
Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** Download the latest version [here](http://www.proftpd.org/) and compile your own version. Currently there is no PPA for Ubuntu 12.04 with the version 1.3.4e/1.3.5.

---

Compile your own version

It is possible that you need some development libraries. If so, drop me a comment.

```
cd
wget ftp://ftp.proftpd.org/distrib/source/proftpd-1.3.4e.tar.gz
tar xf proftpd-1.3.4e.tar.gz
cd proftpd-1.3.4e
./configure
make
```

Install with `make` (the classic way)

```
sudo make install
```

Or with `aptitude` for a deb package

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
sudo aptitude
```